# Generating Bitcoin address from ECDSA Public Key

Tags: c++, c, openssl, bitcoin

I'm writing simple code in C++ using OpenSSL to generate valid bitcoin address - private key pair.

I'm using this snippet to generate public key from given hex-form private key:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>

int main()
{
     EC_KEY *eckey = NULL;
     EC_POINT *pub_key = NULL;
     const EC_GROUP *group = NULL;
     BIGNUM start;
     BIGNUM *res;
     BN_CTX *ctx;



     BN_init(&start);
     ctx = BN_CTX_new(); // ctx is an optional buffer to save time from allocating and deallocating memory whenever required

     res = &start;
     BN_hex2bn(&res,"30caae2fcb7c34ecadfddc45e0a27e9103bd7cfc87730d7818cc096b1266a683");
     eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
     group = EC_KEY_get0_group(eckey);
     pub_key = EC_POINT_new(group);

     EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, res);

     /* pub_key is a new uninitialized `EC_POINT*`.  priv_key res is a `BIGNUM*`. */
     if (!EC_POINT_mul(group, pub_key, res, NULL, NULL, ctx))
       printf("Error at EC_POINT_mul.\n");

     EC_KEY_set_public_key(eckey, pub_key);

     char *cc = EC_POINT_point2hex(group, pub_key, 4, ctx);

     char *c=cc;

     int i;

     for (i=0; i<130; i++) // 1 byte 0x42, 32 bytes for X coordinate, 32 bytes for Y coordinate
     {
       printf("%c", *c++);
     }

     printf("\n");

     BN_CTX_free(ctx);

     free(cc);

     return 0;
}
```

What I want is to transform this Public Key to bitcoin address - what is the fastest way to achieve it? I don't know how to create RIPEMD160 from OpenSSL's BIGNUM. Or maybe there is another, better solution?

Comment: do you have the resulting code? sounds interesting

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming what you're doing is based on this conversion:

[image]

I'll describe what you can do in pseudo-code:

First extract x, y from public key.

```
// get x and y from Public key "point"
EC_POINT_get_affine_coordinates_GFp(group, pub_key, x, y, ctx);
// convert BIGNUMs x, y into binary form
BN_bn2bin(x,x_char);
BN_bn2bin(y,y_char);
```

Next you need to do message digest several times, including 3 sha256 and 1 ripemd160. In the following pseudo-code I'll show you how to do ripemd160. To do sha256 with EVP_MD, just replace `EVP_ripemd160()` with `EVP_sha256()`, and update (input to EVP_MD) your input message with single or several `EVP_DigestUpdate()`.

```
EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
EVP_MD_CTX_init(&md_ctx);
EVP_DigestInit(&md_ctx, EVP_ripemd160());
// hdr = 0x04
EVP_DigestUpdate(&md_ctx,hdr,1);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&md_ctx,x_char,32);
EVP_DigestUpdate(&md_ctx,y_char,32);
// put message degest into dgst and set length to dgstlen
EVP_DigestFinal(&md_ctx,dgst,&dgstlen); 
EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&md_ctx);
```

Or the easier way, call `sha256()` and `ripemd160()` directly. But you need to prepare your input message before calling hash functions `sha256()` or `ripemd160()`.

The 25-byte binary address is the result of ripemd160, together with the first 4 bytes of 32-byte checksum. You need to find a way to convert it from Base 256 to Base 58. I don't think OpenSSL support that.

Answer (score 0):

The 25-byte binary address is the result of ripemd160, together with the first 4 bytes of 32-byte checksum. You need to find a way to convert it from Base 256 to Base 58. I don't think OpenSSL support that.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bL52hFkZg9L2jIPdhEKw35ooFK78w1qm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

All right, rewrote some of the steps to generate your private key from your code snip above

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/ripemd.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char* to_base58(const uint8_t* data, size_t size) {
    static char base58chars[] = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    BN_CTX* ctx = BN_CTX_new();
    BIGNUM num, div, rem, B58;
    BN_init(&num);
    BN_init(&div);
    BN_init(&rem);
    BN_init(&B58);
    BN_bin2bn(data, size, &num);
    BN_set_word(&B58, 58);
    char* result = (char*)malloc(100);
    memset(result, 0, 100);
    int index = 99;
    while (BN_cmp(&num, BN_value_one()) > 0) {
        BN_div(&div, &rem, &num, &B58, ctx);
        BN_copy(&num, &div);
        uint64_t r = BN_get_word(&rem);
        result[--index] = base58chars[r];
    }
    result[--index] = base58chars[BN_get_word(&num)];
    BN_CTX_free(ctx);
    return result + index;
}

void print_hex(uint8_t* data, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%02x", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    uint8_t pubKey[65];
    size_t pubKeyLen = 65;
    EC_KEY* key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
    BIGNUM* privKey = BN_new();
    BN_hex2bn(&privKey, "30caae2fcb7c34ecadfddc45e0a27e9103bd7cfc87730d7818cc096b1266a683");
    EC_KEY_set_private_key(key, privKey);
    EC_KEY_generate_key(key);
    EC_KEY_check_key(key);
    EC_POINT_point2oct(EC_KEY_get0_group(key), EC_KEY_get0_public_key(key), POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, pubKey, pubKeyLen, NULL);
    uint8_t hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256(pubKey, sizeof(pubKey), hash);
    uint8_t ripeHash[RIPEMD160_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    RIPEMD160(hash, sizeof(hash), ripeHash);
    uint8_t extendedRipe[1 + RIPEMD160_DIGEST_LENGTH + 4];
    extendedRipe[0] = 0x00;
    memcpy(extendedRipe + 1, ripeHash, sizeof(ripeHash));
    SHA256(extendedRipe, sizeof(ripeHash) + 1, hash);
    SHA256(hash, sizeof(hash), hash);
    memcpy(extendedRipe + 21, hash, 4);
    printf("Bitcoin address: %s\n", to_base58(extendedRipe, sizeof(extendedRipe)));
    return 0;
}
```